# Can't understand JavaScript Recursion call output

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having some confusion with this code.  When I make the recursive call, will the line document.writeln() get executed each time the call is made? Or when will the document.writeln() get executed?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
  var a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];

  someFunction( a, 0 );

  function someFunction( b, x )
  {
   if ( x < b.length ) {
    someFunction( b, x + 1 ); //recursive call
    document.writeln( b[ x ] + " " );
   }
  }
</SCRIPT>
```

thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for the recursive function here? Why not use a simple `for()` loop?

Comment: This will print the items in reverse order. If you swap the lines with `someFunction` and `document.write` it will print the items in-order.

Comment: I am just trying to understand recursion. I know it can be done using a for loop with reverse counter but can't get to understand the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you pass `x+1` to the recurisive call. Eventually, this will cause `x` to be equal `b.length` and function will return. All the nested writes will execute (bigger `x`s first).

Here is the expanded version:

```
function someFunction(b, x) {
    if (x < b.length) {
        if (x+1 < b.length) {
            if (x+2 < b.length) {
                if (x+3 < b.length) {
                  ... // Eventually the condition will be false.
                }
                document.writeln(b[x+2] + " ");
            }
            document.writeln(b[x+1] + " " );
        }
        document.writeln(b[x] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: This also helps a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Visualising a recursion call tree as steps might help:

```
1. foo1()
2.     foo2()
3.         foo3()
4.         document.write()
5.     document.write()
6. document.write()
```

Taking this example, try visualising what the tree would look like if the `document.write` call was before the recursive call.

Comment: There is actually one more `foo` call in there that _doesn't_ do a `document.write`.

Comment: You're right! I didn't mean write it out for his exact code--only to show how to visualise a recursive call tree. Good point though!

Answer (score 0):

document.writeln() gets executed each time the function is called(on condition untill If statement inside the function returns true). Hence the output for the function is 
        "10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1"